# Trying to send html content in a JSON format using Python to Joomla API

Tags: json, python-3.x, joomla

Variable 'article' prints like this:

> [MessageContentText(text=Text(annotations=[], value='some long <p class="break">html</p> here'), type='text')]

Python code looks like JSON like this

```
data = {
        'title': {blog_post_idea},
        'alias': {slug},
        'articletext': {article},
        'catid':'0',
        "language": "*"
}
```

I tried `article["value"]` and `article[1]` various list type errors. I don't know if the API I am sending to can decode base64 or not. I am trying to send html.

Comment: which api are you sending to? you should simply check what it expects, and format your payload accordingly. Are you using com_ajax? Can you get authenticated?

Comment: This worked for me ty for insights. 'articletext':element.text.value